# Xtext: Use EClass in XExpression

Tags: xtext, ecore, xbase

I am writing on a **Xtext** grammar that uses **XExpressions** and also operates on **Eclasses**. Now I want to also be able to access **Eclasses** from the **XExpression**, for example I write an expression like this:

```
Eclass1.attribute1 = Eclass2.attribute1
```

I would like to know, how I can use the **Eclass** from within the **XExpression**?

**Grammar**

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.Mydsl with 
org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

generate mydsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/Mydsl"

Model:
(operations += Operation)*;

terminal ATTR : ID ('.' ID)+;

Operation:
'operation' left=[ecore::EClass|ATTR] 'and' right=
 [ecore::EClass|ATTR] 'defined' 'as' condition=XExpression
;
```

**Inferrer/ Infer method**

```
def dispatch void infer(Model element, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
      acceptor.accept(element.toClass("example.mydsl")) [
        for (operation : element.operations) {
            left = operation.left
            right = operation.right
            if (left.eIsProxy()) {
                left = EcoreUtil.resolve(left, operation) as EClass
            }   
            if (right.eIsProxy()) {
                right = EcoreUtil.resolve(right, operation) as EClass
            }
            //field for right class left out, but works the same
            members += left.toField(left.name,typeRef(left.EPackage.name+"."+left.name))    
            members += operation.toMethod("conditionExpr", 
            typeRef(Void.TYPE)) [
                body = operation.condition
            ]       
        }
    ]

}
```

**RuntimeModule**

```
    class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

       def Class<? extends ImplicitlyImportedFeatures> bindImplicitlyImportedTypes() {
       return MyImportFeature
}

}
```

**MyImportFeature**

```
class MyImportFeature extends ImplicitlyImportedFeatures{
override protected getStaticImportClasses() {
    (super.getStaticImportClasses() + #[PackageFromWorkSpace]).toList
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Am not sure if i get your question.
Ususally EMF generates constants for EAttributes so if you want to access the attributes themselfs
so you could either do
`MyDslPackage.Literals.GREETING__NAME`
or
`MyDslPackage.eINSTANCE.getGreeting_Name()`

can you give some more hints on what you actually want to do

update: here is a snippet on how to get a java class from a reference to an eclass

```
Thingy:{
    val EClass eclazz = f.clazz
    val uri = EcorePlugin.getEPackageNsURIToGenModelLocationMap(true).get(eclazz.EPackage.nsURI)
    val rs = new ResourceSetImpl
    val r = rs.getResource(uri, true)
    r.load(null)
    val p = r.contents.head
    if (p instanceof GenModel) {
        val genClass = p.findGenClassifier(eclazz)
        if (genClass instanceof GenClass) {
            println(genClass.qualifiedInterfaceName)
            members+=f.toField(eclazz.name, genClass.qualifiedInterfaceName.typeRef)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the thing that has the reference to the eclass

Comment: I only have `operation.left` and `operation.right`, but they don´t have `clazz`, although they are of type EClass

Comment: Arrrg of course you have left and right I don't since I have named it clazz I thought that was obvious

Comment: I did the example before knowing your grammar

Comment: `uri` is null, seems like it can´t find `eclazz.EPackage.nsURI` in the map

Comment: where you your eclasses come from? do you have a ecore and a genmodel and code generated?

Comment: how do you do the scping for the eclasses?

Comment: did you consider to simpy reference the java class instead of the eclass as proposed before?

Comment: I do have the ecore, genmodel and generated code. I didn´t do anything with scoping. I didn´t consider referencing the java classes. Could you give an example on how to do this?

Comment: Have a look the domain model example . If you don't have ecore and genmodel where do your eclasses come from

Comment: What do you mean by domain model example, can you provide a link to that?

Comment: I have the ecore and genmodel

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to reproduce your situation

Comment: what did you mean by referencing the java classes instead of eclasses?

Comment: Xxxx=JvmParametrizedTypeReference (see superttype in domain model example)

Comment: sry where can i find this example, can you please provide a link?

Comment: File menu, new, example xtext domain model example

Comment: I forgot to mention that in my runtime Eclipse, I have imported a project with a test file for my grammar and a test ecore model (imdb example). When I open the test file, I can write an expression like `operation imdb.Film and imdb.Actor defined as ...` and at the dots its marked with errors. The point is, that the editor recognizes the EClasses _Actor_ and _Film_ . How can I achive, that _Actor_ and _Film_ can be used in the XExpression? I think, that I need to set a field in the inferrer for _Actor_ and _Film_ but there I´m not sure

Comment: also, I have created a git repo https://github.com/mrftothek/firstDSL with the source code

Comment: argg you dont have a genmodel and no java classes.

Comment: ok so I need the imdb genmodel? and how do I get the java classes? and what do they even represent? is it like generated java classes like from the xtext grammar?

Comment: and yes these are the java classes representing the ecore model

Comment: and you get the java classes by opening,  rightclicking the genmodel root i the genmodel editor and select generate java code

Comment: Christian, it´s working! Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: how can I use the `ATTR` rule as identifier as in my example? when switching from `QualifiedName` to `ATTR`, the XExpression cant find the Java Class anymore for some reason

Comment: Attr conflicts with qualified name from xbase and has to be deleted and replaced with qualified name from xbase

Comment: what´s the reason for that? because it´s a terminal rule?

Comment: Yes. And the lexer eats as much as it can

Comment: hmm ok, I would need to add an import to the generated java class from the inferrer. I saw an approach like this https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/487230/ , where `ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider` is subclassed and then bound in the RuntimeModule. Can I add arbitrary imports with this approach?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do

Comment: I want to have the java class import a package from my workspace. I already added the dependency to it in the xtext project. Can this be achieved by template expressions?

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve ? Setting a body in inferrer ?

Comment: something like members+=entity.toMethod("demo", Void.TYPE.typeRef) [body='''«List»<«String»> list = new «ArrayList»<«String»>();'''] ???

Comment: no, I want to be able to use methods from a package inside of my XExpression. Therefore I think I need to have the generated java class by the inferrer, import this package. So I would need to set the import section for this java class.

Comment: simply use an ximportsection? see domainmodel example

Comment: otherwise customize org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.scoping.batch.ImplicitlyImportedFeatures

Comment: I dont need the import section in my grammar. I just want to be able to access the methods from only this package, inside of my XExpression

Comment: then ImplicitlyImportedFeat‌​ures is the place to look at

Comment: doesnt this require the grammar to use `XImportSection` ?

Comment: no ImplicitlyImportedFeat‌​ures is used to provide e.g. the xbase libary

Comment: https://github.com/xtext/seven-languages-xtext/blob/master/languages/org.xtext.tortoiseshell/src/org/xtext/tortoiseshell/scoping/TortoiseShellImplicitlyImportedFeatures.xtend
I followed this example, I edited the original post. But I can´t see the import of `PackageFromWorkspace` in my inferred java class. Did I override the wrong method?

Comment: You need to add the jar to both the project containing the inferrer and the project containing the model files . And you see it only if you use it. And don't forget the binding the mydslruntimemodule

Comment: And you may have to make sure it's exported in the defining plugin

Comment: https://github.com/xtext/seven-languages-xtext/blob/master/languages/org.xtext.tortoiseshell/src/org/xtext/tortoiseshell/TortoiseShellRuntimeModule.xtend#L25

Comment: Do you mean the example project in the editor by "project containing model files"?

Comment: Yes I mean the project containing the yourdsl files